# Confusion about Actions of the Symmetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I’m working on some practice questions and I am having trouble understanding actions of the symmetric group.

I have the answers, but there were no explanations as to how they were derived. I feel that there is something very fundamental that i am not understanding.

> $(i)$ Let $X=\{ \{i,j,k\} \subset \{1,2,3,4\} \mid |\{i,j,k\}| = 3 \} = $ the set of all $3$ element subsets. What is the number of orbits of $\mathrm{Sym}(4) \curvearrowright X$?

The answer here was given as $1$.

However, I don’t understand this. I have that the elements of $X$ are $\{123\},\{124\},\{234\},\{134\}$ (i.e., choosing combinations of $3$ from $4$).

For example, let $g_1 = (12)(34) \in \mathrm{Sym}(4)$ and say $x_1 = (123) \in X$.

Then $$g_1 \cdot x_1 = (214) \in X \,.$$ (Is this correct? $g_1$ sends $1 \rightarrow 2$, $2 \rightarrow 1$, $3 \rightarrow 4$?)

Similarly let $g_2 = (1234)  \in  \mathrm{Sym}(4)$, then

$$  g_2 \cdot x_1 = (234) \in X \,.$$

So from these two examples, already the orbit of $x_1$ under $G$ are two other elements in $X$, so how can the number of orbits be $1$?

> $(ii)$ Note that Sym($n$) acts on the set of all the subsets of $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ denoted $\rho(\{1,\dotsc,n\})$.  Let $X = \rho( \{1,\dotsc,4\})$. What is the number of orbits of
> $\mathrm{Sym}(4) \curvearrowright X$?

The answer provided here is $5$. Again, I have a misunderstanding here, which is similar to above. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 10-30, 10-30! The elements of $X$ are NOT 3-cycles, i.e. elements of $S_4$. They are subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, so don't use the cycle notation for them. Also, the fact that you can find permutations such as $g_1$ and $g_2$ that map a given element of $X$ to any other is an indication that the number of orbits is small. If there is a permutation $g\in S_4$ such that $g(A)=g(B)$ for some $A,B\in X$, this means that $A$ and $B$ belong to the same orbit of $S_4$.

Comment: In part (ii) you should notice that $A$ and $g(A)$ have the same number of elements for all $g\in S_4$ and all $A\subseteq\{1,2,3,4,\}$.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I think I am getting a better understanding, just to clarify, so I have shown there are two elements of Sym($4$) that send $x_1$ to different elements of $X$ (the same orbit?), So is it true that if there is an element $g_i \in $ Sym($4$) that sends $x_j \in X$ to something $\notin X$ then this is a different orbit? Then how is 'different' orbits actually defined? Thanks again.

Comment: If $g$ sends something in $X$ outside of $X$, then we don't have the group acting on $X$ at all. To get more orbits we need a smaller group or a bigger set. For example, if instead of all of $S_4$ we only look at the subgroup $H$ generated by $g_1=(12)(34)$, then the orbits of $H$ acting on the set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ are $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$. This is because no matter how many times you apply $g_1$, you cannot map $1$ to, say, $3$. Also we might define an action of $G=S_4$ on the set $Y=\{1,2,3,4,-1,-2,-3,-4\}$ by letting $G$ act on the negative numbers by temporarily ignoring the sign.

Comment: (cont'd) In that case $G$ has two orbits on $Y$. One orbit consists of the positive numbers and the other of the negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about size of orbit, not the number of orbits. $X$ is the whole orbit which has $4$ elements.

For the second part, each orbit of $\rho(\{1,\dots,4\}$ contains subsets of $\{1,\dots,4\}$ of the same size. The number of orbits is equal to the number of possible sizes of the subsets which are $0,1,2,3,$ and $4$.

Comment: sorry, I am still confused about the difference between the size of an orbit vs. the number orbits. Am i correct to say that for part $(a)$, since the size of each element resulting from Sym($4$) $\curverightarrow X$ is the same (i.e. a $3$ element subset) - then the number of orbits is $1$? Then in part $(b)$, elements of $X$ can be of sizes $0,1,2,3,4$. And when a $g \in $ Sym($4$) acts on a $x_i \in X$ it sends it to $x_j$ of the same size - so the possible sizes are as mentioned - so the answer is $5$? Is that correct? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

As for $(i)$, the action is:
$$\sigma*\{i,j,k\}:=\{\sigma(i),\sigma(j),\sigma(k)\}$$
You can prove that this is indeed an action of $S_n$ on $X$, for any $n\ge 3$. Next:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Stab}_*(\{i,j,k\}) &= \{\tau\in S_4\mid \tau\cdot\{i,j,k\}=\{i,j,k\}\} \\
&= \{\tau\in S_4\mid \{\tau(i),\tau(j),\tau(k)\}=\{i,j,k\}\} \\
&= \{\tau\in S_4\mid \tau(l)=l, \text{for }l\in \{1,2,3,4\}\setminus\{i,j,k\}\} \\
&= \operatorname{Stab}(l)
\end{alignat}
where the latter stabilizer is the one by $l\space(\ne i,j,k)$ of the natural action of $S_4$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$. But this has clearly order $(4-1)!=6$, whence the $*$-orbit by $\{i,j,k\}$ has size $\frac{4!}{6}=4=|X|$, and hence there is one single $*$-orbit.

This argument can be generalized this way: each cardinality of the subsets of $S:=\{1,2,3,4\}$ corresponds to one orbit of the $*$-action of $S_4$ on the power set $\mathcal{P}(S)$. So, $5$ orbits overall, corresponding to the sizes $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$.

Answer (score 0):

The first action is *transitive*, so that the number of orbits is one.

The second action is on $X=\mathscr P(\{1,2,3,4\})$, the set of subsets (power set) of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  But, $S_4$ acts via bijections.  So it takes sets of given size to sets of the same size. It also transitive on each set of subsets of given size.

Thus the number of orbits is the number of possible sizes of subsets.   For a set of order $4$, that's $5$.

More generally,  if $S_n$ acts on $\mathscr P(\{1,2,\dots, n\})$, in the same way, the number of orbits is $n+1$.

Comment: How can you get this all without making explicit the action on the subsets?

Comment: Well,  I took it to be the obvious one.   Apply the permutation to the subset.  That gives you another subset of the same size.  @Devo

Comment: You can probably do others.  @Devo. So your point is probably valid.